# Reading in multiple csv files, adding file name, but all columns combining?

Tags: import, lapply, coercion

I am reading in multiple csv files (~50) from a folder and combining them into a single dataframe. I want to keep their original file names attached to their data and add it as its own column.

I have run this code:

```
all_paths <-
  list.files(path = "C:/Users/pwern/Documents/Maui Tiger Shark Acoustic Monitoring/Maui Tiger Shark Acoustic Monitoring/data inputs/Vemco Receiver Files/relevant maui detection files",
             pattern = "*.csv",
             full.names = TRUE)

all_content <-
  all_paths %>%
  lapply(read.table,
         header = TRUE,
         sep = "|",
         encoding = "UTF-8")

all_filenames <- all_paths %>%
  basename() %>%
  as.list()

all_lists <- mapply(c, all_content, all_filenames, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

all_result <- rbindlist(all_lists, fill = T)
```

but my all_result df ends up with only two columns, the first of which is all my data combined into one column and the second is the file names. I can't figure out where I am going wrong with the separation? Thank you in advance for your help